# Postgresql cast seconds to time without time zone

Tags: postgresql, casting

I have some table (1) with a column of type bigint that has the time in seconds. I also have another table (2) that has the time as "time without timezone". When I do

`INSERT INTO 2 SELECT time FROM 1`

it gives me an error:

> column "time" is of type time without time zone but expression is of
>   type bigint.

Is there any way to cast seconds to time without time zone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT '142 second'::interval::time without time zone
```

In your case it will look something like

```
(seconds_column || ' second')::interval::time without time zone
```